# How to pass parameters (other than event) to event handlers?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

The following code renders 3 buttons with label "1", "2" and "3". Clicking on each button will alert the label.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var a = [1, 2, 3];
                $.each(a, function(i, ai) {
                    $('<button />').text(i).appendTo('body')
                        .click(function() {alert(i);});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if I replace `function() {alert(i);}` with `foo` and define `function foo() { alert(i); }`, I will get an error of `variable i is not defined`.

So how to pass parameters (other than event) to event handlers? I think defining the event handler (`foo()` in this case) as a named function will make the code cleaner if the event handler is long and complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
                var a = [1, 2, 3];
                $.each(a, function(i, ai) {
                    $('<button />').text(i).appendTo('body')
                        .click(function() { foo.apply(this,[i]);});
                });
            });


function foo( i )
{
   alert( i + " : " + $(this).text() );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `foo.call`?  `apply` takes an array.

Comment: why create an array?  `foo.call(this, i);` would be a bit simpler.

Comment: I like this answer. The most succinct one IMO. I guess Ghommey use `apply()` instead of `call()` because `apply()` can be used for passing multiple parameters which is a more general case.

Comment: @powerboy - Both can be used to pass multiple arguments. `apply()` requires the data to be packed in an array, while `call()` can take any number of arguments after the scope parameter. So these two statements are equivalent: `myfunction.apply(this,[1,2,3,'four'])` and `myfunction.call(this,1,2,3,'four')`. In practice, I've found it easier and more natural to use `call()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [the documentation for `bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), you'll see it has an optional `eventData` parameter. So for example this would work:

```
function foo(e)
{
    alert(e.data.theI);
}

$(function ()
{
    var a = [1, 2, 3];
    $.each(a, function (i, ai)
    {
        $('<button/>').text(i).appendTo('body').bind("click", {theI: i}, foo);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A third method, and the way I usually do it is to invoke a function that returns your handler. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var bindFoo = function(x) {
                return function() {alert(x);};
            };
            $(function() {
                var a = [1, 2, 3];
                $.each(a, function(i, ai) {
                    $('<button />').text(i).appendTo('body')
                        .click(bindFoo(i));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using `x` in the binding function only to distinguish it from `i` in the main code block.